# How can i create a user with password in EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, password, users

I have an EC2 instance on which i have set up a Git server. Now to access this server from eclipse plugin outside, i need a username/password for an instance user.

All i can see is that i have user but a ssh key file/ppk file using which i can connect. Can anyboldy help me on how can i create user with password on same instance & access the instance from this user from outside say eclipse?

Regards.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to enable password authentication first before setting a user password. To do that:

1. Edit the sshd configuration file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` as root.
2. Find the parameter `PasswordAuthentication`. Make sure it's uncommented and set to `yes`.
3. Save the file and exit. Restart ssh service for this to take effect.

Now, using the following command to set the user password:

```
passwd UserName
```

That's it! You should try to login now without the key file.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps to achieve this.

1. Please create a user with below command

`sudo adduser new_user`

2. Then fire below command to edit the parameter `PasswordAuthentication`. Make sure it's uncommented and set to `yes`

`sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

3. After step number 2, please fire below command

`sudo service sshd restart`

4. And then generate the password for the user

`sudo passwd new_user`

Now you are all set to login now with user name and password. Make sure to use public IP of the server while logging in

Answer (score -2):

Try:

`#sudo passwd username`

Then enter your desired password.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i tried to create a new user in EC2 instance using command line and provided password but when trying to connect using eclipse, could not succeed. Any idea?